# How to use xquery to extract form data from html?

Tags: xquery, xidel

```
<form action='https://myurl.com' name='form2' id="form2" method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='abc' value='xxx'>
    <input type="hidden" name="efg" value="yyy">
</form>
```

Suppose that I have the above form in an HTML page, I'd like to extract the data to be posted `abc=xxx&efg=yyy` and print it to stdout. Does anybody know how to do it with `xidel`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML file is saved as test.html, the following xidel command will return the results you're expecting:

```
xidel test.html --xpath="string-join(//input ! (@name || '=' || @value), '&')"
```

The results:

```
**** Retrieving: test.html ****
**** Processing: test.html ****
abc=xxx&efg=yyy
```

If the HTML is on an HTTP server, just replace `test.html` with the URL:

```
xidel http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/test.html --xpath="string-join(//input ! (@name || '=' || @value), '&')"
```

Results:

```
**** Retrieving (GET): http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/test.html ****
**** Processing: http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/test.html ****
abc=xxx&efg=yyy
```

(Note that Xidel was forgiving with the unescaped ampersand, which I originally expected would throw an error, but I tried because there doesn't seem to be an explicit option for `output:method='text'`.

Comment: On a single line within quotes that's no problem. Only when the command spans multiple lines does the ampersand need to be escaped; `^&`. Btw, when using `--xquery` that would be `^&amp;`.